# amCharts5 setting Map data causes it to disappear

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

I have initialized a Map, set heatRules and then set the data on the `polygonSeries` by calling `polygonSeries.data.setAll()`.

Everything works fine until I try to set new data on the `polygonSeries`. When I call `polygonSeries.data.setAll()` from a separate function, but with new data, the whole map just disappears.